# The distribution of n positive real numbers with fixed sum

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology

What is the **term** for the distribution for positive real numbers `(x,y,z)` whose sum are 1 ?

This is the case `n=3`, it is a uniform distribution on a certain triangle on 3 dimension.

I remember that I heard it before, but I can't find it with keywords search in google or wikipedia.

Thank you!

Comment: Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: I would call this the uniform distribution on the open 2-simplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, this is the uniform distribution on the open $2$-simplex, a [special case of the symmetric Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases) with parameter $\alpha=1$.